# Why do row equivalent matrices need to have same number of rows?

Tags: linear-algebra

If any two rows of a $3×3$ matrix A turn out to be same and if we remove that row and it turns out that this new matrix  is row equivalent  to a $2×3$ matrix B then can we say matrix A is row equivalent to  matrix B?

Comment: Can't we remove a row if it has all entries equal to zero because it is like writing the same equation twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an equivalence where you allow deletion and insertion of rows that are only zero. It would correspond to, say, taking a linear transformation whose image is the $xy$ plane of $\Bbb R^3$, and saying it's image is basically $\Bbb R^2$, so we *make* it $\Bbb R^2$.

But that wouldn't be the concept we know as row equivalence. Is it more useful than row equivalence? Probably not, since it's not in wide-spread use. I'm sure it's useful in some applications.

Comment: Is this true even if a row has all entries equal to zero?

Comment: Okay, I think that answers the question.